# invalid decimal literal (uuid.py, line 138) using Python 3.12 in AWS Lambda

Tags: uuid, python-3.12

Im trying to generate a token with uuid in Lambda with Python 3.12 runtime. I installed last uuid in my local venv with Python 3.12 and use it as Lamdba Layer, but have the problem:

```
[ERROR] Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': invalid decimal literal (uuid.py, line 138)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/uuid.py" Line 138
                if not 0 <= time_low < 1<<32L:
```

Here is my code:

```
import uuid

def lambda_handler(event, context):
.
.
.
if response.status_code == 200:
            tokens = response.json()
            print("Token de acceso obtenido de Spotify: ", tokens['access_token'])
            session_token = str(uuid.uuid4())
            try:
                response = table.put_item(
                Item={
                    'session_token': session_token,
                    'access_token': tokens['access_token'],
                    'refresh_token': tokens['refresh_token'],
                    # Puedes guardar también otros datos como 'expires_in', 'scope', etc.
                    }
                )
```

Is not a problem of Lambda Layers because all libreries are importing ok, also install the last version on uuid with pip, so I dont know what the problem is :(

Answer (score 1):

I just delete uuid library from the Lambda Layer, so it seems that by default Python3.12 have uuid in AWS Lambda